# Specific name of each year as per Indian Panchang System

Tags: calendar, panchang

I received one WA msg saying that as per Indian Panchang system, each year has a specific name? And that each name has a meaning? There are 60 names of years (Samvatsars). Each name replays after 60 years. The year typically begins in mid-April.

> The year 2019-20 was named ‘Vikari’, that lived up to its name by
> being a ‘repulsive’ year!
>
> The year 2020-21 was named ‘Sharvari’, meaning darkness, and it did
> push the world into a dark place!
>
> Now the ‘Plava’ year (2021-22) is beginning. ‘Plava’ means that, which
> ferries us across. The Varaha Samhita says: this will ferry the world
> across unbearable difficulties and reach us to a state of glory. And
> take us from darkness to light!

Also there was a followup msg with list of Name of the year.

I wanted to understand that is there any scriptural reference of such claim?